# How can I convert an R Project into a Quarto Project?

Tags: r, project, quarto

I'm a researcher/data analyst, and most of my workflows involve multiple, sequential quarto documents within the same R Project. For example, my typical project directory looks something like this:

```
* project-name.RProj
* Data
  * survey-results.csv
  * cleaned-results.RDS
* R
  * 01_read-and-clean-data.qmd
  * 02_analyse-results.qmd
```

Recently I've been investigating GitHub actions that can render all of the Quarto documents in sequence. It is possible with my current set up, but it would be much simpler if my project was a Quarto project.

How can I turn this project into a Quarto project, preferably without rewriting the entire repository?

Comment: Try with putting a `_quarto.yml` file in the current project root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `_quarto.yml` in the root of the directory.

You could go the full website route, by specifying under project `type: website` with its own array of options, but it is pretty easy to just specify html format for each file.

The [quarto website](https://quarto.org/) has good documentation for everything.

Here's an example file `_quarto.yml` to render each `.qmd` file into html format. Adjust, add, or delete some of these settings to your liking.

```yaml
project:
  title: "Project title"
  output-dir: reports
format:
  html:
    theme:
      - lumen
      - assets/styles.scss
    highlight-style: github
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    toc-location: left
    self-contained: true
    code-tools: true
    grid:
      sidebar-width: 300px
      body-width: 1000px
      margin-width: 300px
      gutter-width: 1.5rem
```

Example of `styles.scss`:

```css
/*-- scss:rules --*/
pre>code.sourceCode {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

I'll usually put each `.qmd` script in the root of the project's directory, and you'll only need to specify the basics in the frontmatter of each file, e.g.,

```yaml
---
title: Script 1
author: John Doe
date: 2023-10-31
---
```

Once you're ready, run `quarto render` in the terminal from the project's root directory.

This template is working for for my current setup with Quarto v1.3.450